# __call()__ got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio

I'm experimenting with using user inputs and Twilio to create a "new messaging platform". (It sounds ridiculous, I know, but I mainly want to see if this would work.) Anyway, when I am running my python code, it throws the error **call()** got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'. I don't know if this is my formatting or something else, but it's really annoying because I'm pretty close to being finished. Here's my code:

```
account_sid = 'AC4b7b29794774f13edbaeb19121730dbb'
auth_token = '---'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


def sendText():
  myNum = '+19737848243'
  num = input('Enter your sender\'s phone number here: ')
  text = input('Enter your message here: ')
  myNum = str(myNum)
  text = str(text)
  num = str(num)
  message = client.messages(
        body=text,
        from_=myNum,
        to=num
)
  print(message.sid)
sendText()
```

(BTW I'm not showing my auth_token on this post, so that's not the error. Trust me.)

Any help would be *gladly* appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Ok. Here it is: `__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body' `

Comment: Twilio docs are terrible for reference, but every [code example I can](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api?code-sample=code-send-a-simple-sms-using-the-programmable-sms-api&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x#linkcode) find uses `client.messages.create(args go here)` (and the arguments to `create` seem to match what you're passing), they don't call `client.messages` itself. Did you mean to call `create`?

Comment: Oh my gosh it worked! Thanks so much! Funny how one small error can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this shows as answered, converting my comment:

You're [supposed to call the `create` method of `messages`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api?code-sample=code-send-a-simple-sms-using-the-programmable-sms-api&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x#linkcode), not `messages` itself:

```
client.messages.create(body=text,
    from_=myNum,
    to=num)
```

`messages` appears to be callable, but what it's supposed to be used for is not made clear in the documentation, and clearly it doesn't take the args you were passing.